# How to convert base64 data:url to link url?

Tags: java, android

example I have url : data:image/png;base64,ajshgvdkau....

I want to convert it to : http://example.com/pic.png

is there any code to do this in java android ?

==================================

Edit 1

I'm trying to put the image from url and display it to textview. when i use case 2, the image display perfectly,

but in case 1 not. there is error "unknown protocol: data" and "W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color"

```
        //case 1
//          String base_url = "<p>Image 1 : <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...

        //case 2
        String base_url = "<p>Image 1 : <img src=\"http://example.com/android/tryout/logo.png\"></img></p>";

        Spanned span2 = Html.fromHtml(base_url,getImageHTML(),null);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.target);
        tv.setText(span2);
```

and this is my function

```
public Html.ImageGetter getImageHTML() {

    Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            try {
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(source).openStream(), "src");
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                return drawable;
            } catch(IOException exception) {
                Log.v("IOException", exception.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    return imageGetter;
}
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: i don't think you understand what the first url is. It actually is _the image_. The image is not hosted anywhere, so there is no http url to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I'm using Base64InputStream. Delete "data:image/jpeg;base64," first to get valid base64 code.

```
 public Html.ImageGetter getImageHTML() {

    Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            try {

                String[] str = source.split("base64");

                Base64InputStream is = new Base64InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(str[1].getBytes()), 0);

                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte);

                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                return drawable;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.getMessage();
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    return imageGetter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Base64 class to decode the encoded string as byte array https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

`byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedUrl, Base64.DEFAULT);`

and then you can create bitmap from the byte array.

```
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

please make sure to remove meta info (ie. data:image/png;base64,) when decode the url.
UPDATE:
here sample based on your code:

```
public Html.ImageGetter getImageHTML() {

    Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            try {
                String base64Image = source.substring("data:image/jpeg;base64,".length);
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources()/*or other way to get resource reference*/, bitmap);
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                return drawable;
            } catch(IOException exception) {
                Log.v("IOException", exception.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    return imageGetter;
}
```

Comment: Trims bro. saya coba dulu :)

Comment: Please don't use Bahasa Indonesia, though I'm a native of Indonesia, because majority of people here don't know our language ;)

Comment: @AhmadBudiU why not try my sample code? anyway I update my answer

Comment: great, you should mark the answer as correct answer or you can post the right answer if you found the other way, so other dev can learn from it.